# "Last Business Day" smart mailbox for Apple Mail

Tags: email, apple-mail, smart, mailbox

I have a handy smart mailbox for "Yesterday" with a simple condition

```
Date received - is yesterday
```

However, on Mondays this returns the results from Sunday. I would like to have the last business day. Something like

```
Date received - is yesterday
OR (
  Date received - is exactly - 3 - Days - ago  AND
  "Today's date is a Monday"
)
```

Is it possible to formulate such a condition in Mail?